# Notepad++ Delete all lines with a word that aren't in a wordlist

Tags: email, notepad++

I want to delete all lines with emails that aren't in my wordlist.
For example, I have a txt file with:

```
12benb@example.com Jonh Smith
13chowie@example.com Chowi Gonzalle
17hughes@example.com David Adams
187379@example.com Jonhy B
187fijian@example.com Bob Park
```

And I have a txt file with a list of emails like:

```
187379@example.com    
darrellimbert@example.com
darrellthompson@example.com
daryl@example.com
```

And if any line of the previous file don't have any of these emails in it, delete all lines.

Comment: I hope these aren't real addresses

Comment: I don't hink  you can do that in Notepad++, but you can use Excel. Some `VLOOKUP` functions should do the trick nicely.

Comment: I dont think Notepad++ can do that, but grep can do it. If your first list is `file1.txt` and your second is `file2.txt`, this will get you all of the lines in `file1.txt` that match a line in `file2.txt`: `grep -f file2.txt file1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If the work list is small then you can do a Notepad++ regular expression search for `word1|word2|word3`. In the search window select the 'Mark' tab, tick 'Bookmark lines' and then 'Mark all'. Next select Menu => Search => Bookmark => Remove unmarked lines.

For a large set of words I would recommend Alex's idea in the comment but add the -v option to find lines that do not match, use `grep -v -f wordlist textfile`.